# Is it possible to spawn any kind of terminal on dedicated lan card before entering LVM volume passphrase?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, telnet, lvm

I got IBM x3500 m2 server running Ubuntu server on encrypted LVM volume.

This machine has one slower LAN card for service purposes.

Is there any way to spawn some kind of console on it BEFORE typing LVM passphrase and fully booting the system? I'm tired of plugging keyboard to it and typing in in the blind.

Comment: Serial cable and connecting that to another machine which you then use as jump pad into the (not fully booted) Ubuntu server with the LVM password prompt? The kernel allows you to give all of the console output also on the serial console.

Comment: You might want to look into a KVM over IP PCI adapter such as [this one](http://www.aten.com/products/KVM/KVM-over-IP-Switches/Remote-Management-PCI-Card~IP8000.html).

Comment: as far as I know the Lan I mentioned is on such card,integrated. But I still see it in ifconfig

Comment: clarification to above -  the parts I'm reffering to are :Remote Supervisor Adapter II SlimLine and Intelligent Platform Management Interface. Can I use any of them? I would rather not introduce any customization to kernel